# Can I use the same VHD file to switch back and forth between boot to VHD and a Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, vhd, boot-to-vhd

I'd like to physically install Windows 8.1 Pro and convert my existing physical Windows 7 machine to a VHD as I'd like the convenience of using a Hyper-V virtual machine to access it without having to reboot. But I'd like to retain the option to boot directly to the VHD if I need to use more memory, etc.

Is this possible or will I encounter issues switching back and forth between the VM and booted environments? I am thinking that Windows will detect hardware changes every time I switch access methods if it even works at all.